# How to concatenate with a string each element of a list in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've got a list of string element in a ansible var. I'm looking how to append to each element of the list with a defined string.

Do you know how I can do? I didn't find a way to do so.

**Input:**

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

**Output:**

```
[ "a-Z", "b-Z", "c-Z" ]
```

Answer (score 17):

I really didn't like using the add-on filters or the loop.  However, I stumbled across this blog post https://www.itix.fr/blog/ansible-add-prefix-suffix-to-list/ that used a different method that worked in Ansible 2.9.x.

```
- set_fact:
    output: "{{ list_to_suffix | product(['-Z']) | map('join') | list }}"
```

Comment: Useful tip - the blog also shows how to handle the prefix case.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `join` for this. Please see the code below:

playbook -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    input: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      set_fact:
        output: "{{ output | default([]) + ['-'.join((item,'Z'))] }}"
      loop: "{{ input | list}}"

    - debug:
        var: output
```

output -->

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=c)

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": [
        "a-Z",
        "b-Z",
        "c-Z"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 7):

With simple filters

```py
    shell> cat filter_plugins/string_filters.py
    def string_prefix(prefix, s):
        return prefix + s
    def string_postfix(postfix, s):
        return s + postfix
    class FilterModule(object):
        ''' Ansible filters. Python string operations.'''
        def filters(self):
            return {
                'string_prefix' : string_prefix,
                'string_postfix' : string_postfix
            }
```

the tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ input|map('string_prefix', '-Z')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: output
```

give

```yaml
    "output": [
        "a-Z", 
        "b-Z", 
        "c-Z"
    ]
```

The same output gives the loop below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ output|default([]) + [item + '-Z'] }}"
      loop: "{{ input }}"
    - debug:
        var: output
```

Comment: Indeed these filters do not seem to exist

Comment: They and some more live [here](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/tree/master/filter_plugins). See [examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 7):

Below is how both prefix and suffix can be done in one line

```
  - debug:
    var: result
  vars:
    prefix: foo1
    suffix: foo2
    a_list: [ "bar", "bat", "baz" ]
    result: "{{ [prefix] | product(a_list) | map('join') | list | product([suffix]) | map('join') | list }}"
```

Comment: ty so much for this elegant / extremely human readable snippet of a self contained correct example. Now my code's both working and readable :)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution, for pre-fixing and post-fixing, without custom filters (which make a very elegant code, by the way):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    input: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    suffix: '-Z'
    prefix: 'A-'

- debug:
    var: suffixed
  vars:
    suffixed: "{{ input | zip_longest([], fillvalue=suffix) | map('join') | list }}"

- debug:
    var: prefixed
  vars:
    prefixed: "{{ [] | zip_longest(input, fillvalue=prefix) | map('join') | list }}"
```

```yaml
    "suffixed": [
        "a-Z",
        "b-Z",
        "c-Z"
    ]

    "prefixed": [
        "A-a",
        "A-b",
        "A-c"
    ]
```

Comment: I don’t understand how `[] | zip_longest(input, fillvalue=prefix) | map('join') | list` to add a prefix to each element of a list can be "elegant" code. Would your future self understand this code in 6 months if you don’t add a comment above it?

Comment: Sorry, I have been misunderstood. I meant "custom filters make a very elegant code", certainly more elegant than mine! However, if someone does not want to create a custom filter, here is another solution, which does not require any extra object, file or Python code.
For the record, I am surprised myself of the fact that I still understand this code more than a year later, but, hey, it is my code, so it is probably closer to my own way of thinking.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the other answers felt a bit cumbersome when I wanted to both append and prepend data, so I ended up using [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_replace_filter.html) with `map` instead, which simplifies things quite considerably in my opinion:

```yaml
- name: Create some data to play with
  set_fact:
    domains:
      - example-one
      - example-two
      - example-three
    tld: com

- name: Demonstrate the method
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        domains
        | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'www.\1.' + tld)
      }}
```

Outputs:

```
TASK [example : Create some data to play with] ****************************
ok: [server]

TASK [example : Demonstrate the method] ***********************************
ok: [server] => {
    "msg": [
        "www.example-one.com",
        "www.example-two.com",
        "www.example-three.com"
    ]
}
```

In writing this answer, I actually found this [documented in the Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions), so it appears this is a recommended method too.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest and easiest to understand solution.

Comment: In the general case you would have to escape any backslashes in the `tld` value before appending it to the replacement string to ensure you are not giving `regex_replace` any additional places to insert a capture group.