# Ansible: How to append string to each value of list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to append a string to each value of a list in ansible, so basically am trying to install multiple pip modules offline using .whl files.

I have two files in /opt/tmp/ path

```
vars:
 DIR: /opt/
 pymongo_modules:
   - pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   - pymongo-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
 
- name: Install the latest pymongo package 
  pip:
    name: "{{DIR}}/tmp/{{ pymongo_modules | join(' ') }}"
    executable: "{{pip_path}}"
```

The above is not working because it's formating like below

```
"name": ["/opt/tmp/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl pymongo-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl"]
```

I can achieve the same with below syntax but I'm getting deprecation warning

```
- name: Install the latest pymongo package 
  pip:
    name: "{{DIR}}/tmp/{{ module }}"
    executable: "{{pip_path}}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ pymongo_modules }}"
  loop_control:
        loop_var: module
```

Expecting value:

```
"name": ["/opt/tmp/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl", "/opt/tmp/pymongo-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl"]
```

Comment: [`with_items` is replaces by `loop` and the `flatten` filter.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items)

Comment: @ceving loop also worked well without warning, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) filter like below. BTW, `DIR` variable already ends with a `/` so do not need an additional `/` before `tmp`.

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ [(DIR  + 'tmp')] | product(pymongo_modules) | map('join', '/') | list }}"
```

Gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=/opt/tmp/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl) => {
    "msg": "/opt/tmp/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/opt/tmp/pymongo-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) => {
    "msg": "/opt/tmp/pymongo-3.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered a similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75494925/365796). In summary, you can  achieve this with `regex_replace` and `map`. It's quite a tidy method and is also in the official Ansible docs, so it seems to be recommended too.