# How to add an argument before each list element in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to add an argument before a string getting from a list with a join. How is that possible?

My List definded as a variable in my `ansible.yaml`:

```yaml
test:
  list:
     - /etc/a
     - /etc/b
     - /etc/c
```

With the above list I would like to get something like this when Ansible is running

`command -p /etc/a -p /etc/b/ -p /etc/c`

The command and argument is just an  example.

How I need to configure my playbook task?

```yaml
- name: Command
  shell: command {{ test.list | map('regex_replace', '(^.*$)', '-p ') |join(' ') }}
```

The results of my task:

```
command -p -p -p
```

**One Solution**

This is working thanks to @Zeitounator

```yaml
- name: Command
  shell: ffmpeg {{ test.list | map('regex_replace', '(^.*$)', '-p \\g<1> ') |join(' ') }}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current task ? Which error do you get ? How is the result different from the one you expect ? Hint: you have no back-reference in your replace string to echo back the expression you captured.

Comment: Another option, but that might add complexity when reading the task, is to use `' -p '` as a glue of the `join`. => `{{ (['ffmpeg'] + test.list) | join(' -p ') }}`

Comment: Just for clarity about backrefs: [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) has plenty of examples.

Comment: with my task i get only the argumtent in the end result `ffmpeg -p -p -p...`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε This is not working...the first element of the list didnt get the argument

Comment: @sokolata you didn't read what I proposed through. Re-read it. As for only getting arguments, you should read what Zeitounator wrote through also: [*Hint: you have no back-reference in your replace string to echo back the expression you captured*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789414/how-to-add-a-argument-before-each-list-element-in-ansible#comment116319789_65789414)

Comment: `'-p \\1'` or `'-p \\g<1>'`

Answer (score 0):

> ***I would like to add an argument before a string getting from a `list` with a `join`.***

I understand that you like to prefix a list.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    test:
      list:
        - /etc/a
        - /etc/b
        - /etc/c

    prefix_argument: ' -p '

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "command{{ [prefix_argument] | product(test.list) | map('join') | list | join() }}"
```

will result into the required output

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: command -p /etc/a -p /etc/b -p /etc/c
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to concatenate with a string each element of a list in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767953/6771046)

---

Comparing both approaches in test using [How to generate a list with a range and save it in a `var` of a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177572/6771046)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    test:
      list: "{{ ['/etc/'] | product(range(0,9999)) | map('join') | list }}"

    prefix_argument: ' -p '

  tasks:

  - name: product
    debug:
      msg: "command{{ [prefix_argument] | product(test.list) | map('join') | list | join() }}"

  - name: regex_replace
    debug:
      msg: "command {{ test.list | map('regex_replace', '(^.*$)', '-p \\g<1> ') | join(' ') }}"
```

the runtime does not differ much

```yaml
PLAY RECAP ********************************************
localhost                  : ok=2

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds

regex_replace ----------------------------------- 0.80s
product ----------------------------------------- 0.63s
...
regex_replace ----------------------------------- 0.78s
product ----------------------------------------- 0.61s
```